# objective-c get current location and store it for later access. timing issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

I want to get the current location on the iphone and use the coordinates for some function calls.

Now I have the problem that when I want to access the coordinates, they are empty. But on the delegate function they are somehow retrieved, but not stored...

The NSLog in `doLocation` does not show any value, but on the `locationmanager` it is shown in the NSLog. Or could this be an NSLog issue?

```c
#pragma mark - Location handling

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)doLocation {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    NSLog(@"debug: coordinates: %@", coordinate); 

    return coordinate; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (!oldLocation ||
        (oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude &&
         oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude)) {

            currentLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            currentLng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;


        } else { // oldLocation
            currentLat = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            currentLng = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        }

    self.currentLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLat longitude:currentLng];

    NSLog(@"debug: self.currentLoc: %@", self.currentLoc);

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

The Debug out is:

> 2013-07-01 15:59:29.382 foobar[3793:c07] debug: coordinates: (null)
>   -doLocation 1: Current location:
>
> 2013-07-01 15:59:35.399 foobar[3793:c07] debug: self.currentLoc:  <+51.50998000,-0.13370000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/1/13, 3:59:35 PM Central European Summer Time

Comment: That's not great code design for CoreLocation. CLLocationManager should be a singleton or else you run the risk of overwriting your location coordinates constantly.

Comment: tryied singelton, thanks for the tip. Still have some problems with the implementation. Do you know a good tutorial where I can get some more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just get the location when delegate fire, so in this point you can get the coordinate, and store in some variable and create a delegate to tell to your object you pick the new coordinate. Use design patters to create this class (Location).

Sample:
.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)didUpdateLocation;
-(void)statusChanged;
@end
@interface Location : CLLocationManager <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    BOOL wantUpdate;
}
@property(strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *lm;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *latitude;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
@property(assign,nonatomic) id delegate;
@property(assign,nonatomic) id delegateStatus;

+(id)shared;
-(void)start;
-(void)update;
@end
```

.m

```
+ (id)shared {
    static Location *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        lm.delegate = self;
        lm.purpose = @"Your purpose";
        lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        wantUpdate = NO;
        delegate = self;
        delegateStatus = self;
    }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)start
    {
        wantUpdate = YES;
        [lm startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    -(void)update
    {
        [lm startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        if(wantUpdate)
        {
            latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

            [lm stopUpdatingLocation];
            [delegate didUpdateLocation];
        }

        [lm stopUpdatingLocation];
        wantUpdate = NO;
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while location  %@",error);
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
    {
        if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {
            if([delegateStatus respondsToSelector:@selector(statusChanged)])
                [delegateStatus statusChanged];
        }
    }
```

Comment: will try that as well. looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

When  `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` is called In your `(CLLocationCoordinate2D) doLocation` method; the GPS starts searching for location. At this very moment it has no coordinates information; so when you try to get the Coordinates value in the next line of code in the same method, it displays a NULL value for the coordinates.

And When location is updated, the `didUpdateToLocation` is automatically called and it is passed with the current location information of the device which is being logged in your `didUpdateToLocation` method. Hope this will make sense.

If you want to store the coordinates information, just declare a struct globally or in a shared variable class and simply assign it with the values you receive in `didUpdateToLocation` delegate. And You can then use those values anywhere in your code sooner or later.